# Function with variable blind to a button xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uibutton

Hi I have a problem i can not send parameter for function

```
-(IBAction)ukazObrat:(NSInteger *)cis {     
    stvrtyViewController *screen = [[stvrtyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
    screen.obratLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12];
    screen.obratLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    screen.obratLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:cis];
    [screen release];   
}
```

I set this function to a button klick but I m unable to compile it when I add parameter to it.

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button.titleLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];    
[button.titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];       
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
[button setTitle:obratLable forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector([self ukazObrat:minus]
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];             
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 250.0, 60.0);
```

It was working until I add there the variable.
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set variable into selector definition. Definition can contain only function name. And number of colons will show compiler how much parameters this function required. Selector for button can have one argument - pointer to event-sender button. If you want to send some data from one controller to another you should create some shared storage for that data.

I use for that purpose singleton class with mutable dictionary inside it.

Comment: you should actually use associative references or a static mutable dictionary in a category on nsobject.` - (NSMutableDictionary *)sharedUserInfo {static NSMutableDictionary *sharedUserInfo = nil;   if (sharedUserInfo) return sharedUserInfo;    /* else alloc a new one and set sharedUserInfo */} `

Comment: My class also handle save/load to/from NSKeyedArchive so it a bit more complex, than you're describe. But main idea is correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonHandler) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Then define buttonHandler as:

```
- (void)buttonHandler {
  [self ukazObrat:minus];
}
```

Manage `minus` however is necessary.